# error creating python3 virtualenv for readthedocs

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, read-the-docs

I am trying to use a local instance of readthedocs to build documentation for a project written in python 3.  (I already have successfully built documentation for one python 2 project).

When I select the option to set The Python interpreter used to create the virtual environment to CPython3.X in the advanced settings, then the build fails, with the command 
   `python3.5 -mvirtualenv --no-site-packages --no-download /home/user/rtd/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/project/envs/latest`

producing the error `/usr/bin/python3.5: No module named virtualenv`.

However `pip3 install virtualenv` yeilds `Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.  I've tried switching to using conda but am having problems with that.  Is there anyway to use virtualenv with the global python 3 installation?

I know from the installation instructions that

> you’ll need to install Python 3 with virtualenv in your system as well.

However it is not clear to me what they are saying there.  Could someone clarify?

Comment: Seems your pip3 is broken as it found virtualenv from python2.7 Try `python3.5 -m pip install virtualenv`.